# ASP.NET Core Docker environment variables if apply migration

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application running in Docker and I need to pass to the container (at start) a bool variable whether on not to apply the migration.

For example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if(newDB)
    Seed(true);
  else
    Seed(false);

 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a configuration variable which value will be overridden an by environment variable on run.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables("APP_");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   var newDB = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["NewDB"]));
(...)
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    (..)
   },
  "NewDB": false
}
```

And when running container pass:
`docker run -e APP_NewDB='true' ...`

Comment: I get an exception saying Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '27': '},....

Comment: are you not missing any comma in your json file? Please share it if you can.

Comment: {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  {
    "NewDB": false
  }
}

Comment: You sholdn't use another braces around the newDB param - braces indicate another struct and you didn't name it, hence the error. Correct one: `{ "Logging": { "IncludeScopes": false, "LogLevel": { "Default": "Warning" } }, "NewDB": false }`